# find last instance of recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following recursive procedure to delete a directory:

```
public static boolean deleteDB(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
    File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
    if (allContents != null) {
        for (File file : allContents) {
            deleteDB(file);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("DB deleted");
    return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
}
```

right now my print statement prints out each time a file or folder is deleted.  How can I catch the last time a deletion occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass flag true for first call and false inside recursive method. Wrap System.out with if(flag)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what Ihar said. Here is an example counting integers down. It is far from graceful but might be helpful to illustrate the problem:

```
public class RecursiveTracker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        deleteSomething(12);
    }

    public static boolean deleteSomething(int counter) {
        if(counter == 0) { 
            return false;
        }
        if(!deleteSomething(--counter) ) { 
            System.out.println("last " + counter);
        } else { 
            System.err.println("This i would not print " + counter);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This will print:

```
last 0
This i would not print 1
This i would not print 2
This i would not print 3
This i would not print 4
This i would not print 5
This i would not print 6
This i would not print 7
This i would not print 8
This i would not print 9
This i would not print 10
This i would not print 11
```

I reckon in your case the condition would be to check whether there are more files to be deleted, or `directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();` returning no more files

Answer (score 1):

You can trace recursive functions by level. Try this:

```
public static boolean deleteDB(File directoryToBeDeleted, int level = 0) {
    File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
    if (allContents != null) {
        for (File file : allContents) {
            deleteDB(file, level+1);
        }
    }
    if(level == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("DB deleted");
    }
    return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
}
```

Comment: Does that even compile in java?

Comment: What’s the problem here?